# What is the Ruby equivalent of preg_quote()?

Tags: ruby, regex

In PHP you need to use `preg_quote()` to escape all the characters in a string that have a particular meaning in a regular expression, to allow (for example) `preg_match()` to search for those special characters.

What is the equivalent in Ruby of the following code?

```
// The content of this variable is obtained from user input, in example.
$search = "$var = 100";
if (preg_match('/' . preg_quote($search, '/') . ";/i")) {
  // …
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `Regexp.escape`.

```
str = "[...]"
re = /#{Regexp.escape(str)}/
"la[...]la[...]la".gsub(re,"") #=> "lalala"
```